# React navigation undefined params

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to pass params into a new screen, and implemented it like mentioned [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html).

**I have the following `TouchableOpacity` button.**

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('SomeScreen', {
      title: 'Title',
      subTitle: 'Subtitle',
    });
  }}
>
```

**On the other page (let's call it Somescreen), I have the following:**

```
render() {
  const { navigation } = this.props;
  const title = navigation.getParam('title');
}
```

But `title` above is undefined:

```
{ params: undefined, routeName: "Somescreen", key: "id-xx" }
```

**My rootStack:**

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  SomescreenA: { screen: SomescreenA },
  SomescreenB: { screen: SomescreenB },
}, { headerMode: 'none' });
```

Why are my params undefined in a new screen?

Comment: Did you try [passing an object to `navigate`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#navigate-link-to-other-screens)?

Comment: @Kraylog, thanks! I currently have the following (which works):

                this.props.navigation.navigate({
                  routeName: 'SomeScreen',
                  params: { title: 'title', subTitle: 'subTitle' }
                });
       
And this in the page:


this.props.navigation.getParam('title');

If you post your suggestion as an answer, I'll happily accept it!

Comment: Great! Happy it worked. Added answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've, unfortunately, encountered cases where `navigate(route, params, ...)` wouldn't pass the `params` object, just like you did.

As a workaround, I use the other variant - `navigate({routeName, params, action, key})` that you can find [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#navigate-link-to-other-screens). It always works.

Comment: Doesn't works actually. Any other solution?

Comment: This is an answer from 2019. The library has changed a lot since then, I suspect.

Comment: I was navigating between stacks so I needed to do this:

`navigation.navigate({
      routeName: 'Stack',
      action: NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: 'Route',
        params: {
          booking,
          startDate: booking.attributes.startDate,
        },
      }),
    });`

Answer (score 39):

If you face a situation where your target screen get `undefined` params, probably you have a nested navigation stack.

Here you have to pass params to the navigate method in this way:

```
navigation.navigate('Root', {
  screen: 'Settings',
  params: { user: 'jane' },
});
```

For more information read this page in the official docs:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much!

Answer (score 9):

In my specific case, I was calling a nested navigator, so I had to manage how send those params to their specific screen, so I did this:

Send params this way...the regular way:

```
    navigation.navigate(
        'OrderNavigator',
        {itemSelected},
    );
```

Then, from navigator stack I did this:

```
const OrderNavigator = ({route: {params}}) => {
return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Order">
        <Stack.Screen name="Order" component={Order} options={{headerShown: false}} initialParams={params} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

};

And that's it. Then from the screen I got them like this:

```
const Order = ({route}) => {
  const {itemSelected} = route.params;
  const {first_name, last_name} = itemSelected;
  return (...)
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me :)

Answer (score 5):

if you are on react navigation v6^ use the `useRoute` hook to access the params object

`const route = useRoute();`

> `useRoute` is a hook that gives access to the route object. It's useful when you cannot pass the route prop into the component directly, or don't want to pass it in case of a deeply nested child.

below is an implementation of this

```
    import { useNavigation, useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { Pressable, Text } from 'react-native';

    function Screen1() {
      const navigation = useNavigation();

      return (
        <Pressable
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.navigate('Screen2', { caption: 'hey' });
          }}
        >
          <Text> Go to Screen 2 </Text>
        </Pressable>
      );
    }

    function Screen2() {
      const route = useRoute();

      return <Text>{route.params.caption}</Text>;
    }
```

Comment: This one worked for me, and it's probably one of the easier solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer workaround did not work for me, so apparently if you use `children` to render your component (in screen options) and pass `route` as a prop, it works